# How to break a table CSVs into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that look like this

```
ID  CustName CustAge  Attrib1      Attrib2
===========================================
1   Tom      23       A1,A3,H7,F4  H2,K9,L2
2   Mike     34       Y2,K1,P7     A4,S9
3   Mary     62       R6,W3        K6,S6,L8
4   John     49       W4,K4,W2,G2  E2,N5
5   Ali      36       W3,R5,H2     E3
6   Mark     22       A2           H9,Q7,T6
```

I want to break it into rows

so it look like this

```
ID  CustName CustAge  Attrib1      AttribNo
===========================================
1   Tom      23       A1           1
1   Tom      23       A3           1
1   Tom      23       H7           1
1   Tom      23       F4           1
1   Tom      23       H2           2
1   Tom      23       K9           2
1   Tom      23       L2           2
2   Mike     34       Y2           1
2   Mike     34       K1           1
2   Mike     34       P7           1
2   Mike     34       A4           2
2   Mike     34       S9           2
```

I tried this but did not work

```
SELECT *, (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(Attrib1, ',')) FROM Customers
```

I also tried

```
SELECT *  
FROM Customers C 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(C.Attrib1, ',')) A1
```

still not good

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Fix your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes it is.).

Comment: @stickybit: That is what he is trying to fix ..... (if I read/understand the question)

Comment: @Luuk: To me it seems like they just want a query to split the data but leave the original data, which is the actual problem, untouched...

Comment: @stickybit: OK point taken, now let's hope that `asmgx` is really going for the correct solution... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `cross apply`:

```
select * from tablename t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Attrib1,',') ss
```

and union would be easiest way to get your final result:

```
select *,1 AttribNo from tablename t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Attrib1,',') s1
union all 
select *,2 AttribNo from tablename t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Attrib2,',') s2
```

Comment: `union all` is querying the table twice which is unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

I would do this with a single `apply`:

```
select t.id, t.custno, t.custage, a.*
from t cross apply
     (select s.value as attrib, 1 as attribno
      from string_split(t.attrib1, ',') s
      union all
      select s.value, 2
      from string_split(t.attrib2, ',') s
     ) a;
```

Comment: The eliminated `union all` version seems to be incorrect (wrong value for `attribno`)